# Pass data efficiently across JNI as well as renderscript

Tags: android, java-native-interface, renderscript

I intend to read YUV frames from JNI level, process them in renderscript and then render them. I am curious if there is an efficient way to pass the blocks of data without too many copy ops. Right now, I am using the `NewDirectByteBuffer()` to return the frames to java as `ByteBuffer`. But it seems like I can't directly construct `Allocation` upon this `ByteBuffer`.

So my question is can I do this in only two copy operations or less?

1. copy the data to the `Allocation`
2. copy the data to the `SurfaceView` (I suppose there is a copy operation at rendering part, like `Canvas.setBitmapy(bmp)`)

Comment: That's right, a `DirectByteBuffer` is not backed by `byte[]`, while `Allocation.copyFrom()` expect arrays or `Bitmap`. I would suggest to use `NewByteArray()` instead of `NewDirectByteBuffer()` to return the frames to java as `byte[]`, which can be used in [`Allocation.copyFrom(byte[])`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/renderscript/Allocation.html#copyFrom(byte[])).

Comment: I suppose there is no difference from copying it to a Java `new byte[]`, right?

Comment: If you are on the Java side, then yes, you can copy YUV buffer to `new byte[]`; but you can allocate `NewByteArray()`, pin it to native `unsigned char*`, and fill the latter with YUV data, avoiding one `memcpy()`.